# Sufficient conditions for $b\not\in I^2$ given that $b\in I$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals, kahler-differentials

Let $I$ be an $R$-ideal in a commutative algebra $B$ over a commutative ring $R.$ Given $b\in I$ I want to prove that $b\not \in I^2$.

Are there any sufficient conditions for showing that $b\not\in I^2$ given that $b\in I$?

---

**Context**

Given a commutative algebra $A$ over a commutative ring $K$ the module of kahler differentials may be defined as $I/I^2$ where $I$ is an $A$-ideal in $A\otimes_K A$ generated by elements of form $1\otimes a - a\otimes 1.$ Kahler differential $d:A\to I/I^2$ is given by formula $d(a)=[1\otimes a - a\otimes 1].$ Thus, I want a sufficient conditions to show that $d(a)\neq 0.$

Comment: The first question is way too broad for a reasonable answer. For the latter, about the Kahler differential, it is sufficient to find some derivation $f:A\to M$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$. By the universal property this implies $d(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with universal property of kahler differentials and some of the corollaries. Nontheless, I thought that more general question may shed some light on this problem.